# Layers isolation in a Toroidal Core

Tags: transformer, core

I want to build a spot welder but I do not have a microwave transformer or any other big one, so I decided to make my own toroidal core by rolling a thin steel sheet.

1- Can I use galvanized steel or it must be only steel.

2- Do I have to  varnish the sheet before rolling it to isolate the layers as in EI cores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be silicon steel - this increases the electrical resistance to about 4 times higher than normal iron. This and the fact that laminations are insulated from each other to minimize eddy currents means you have an uphill struggle.

Regards varnishing, this is usually necessary because the laminates need to be insulated from each other to prevent significantly worsening eddy current losses - without varnish (or treatment to produce oxides) the core will act as a small resistance single turn shorted secondary.

Useful Link [here](http://www.dave-cushman.net/elect/transformers.html)

And another [here](http://ludens.cl/Electron/trafos/trafos.html)

Comment: You ought to edit to directly address point 2.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast done!

Comment: I read about silicon steel but it is not available in my small town and surrounding. if i have to choose between galvanized steel (0.3 mm thick) and steel (0.5 mm thick) which one is better?